# Should I build "yet another whiteboard" app for Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, image

I am developing a note taking app. I want to allow users to draw pictures as well as editing existing pictures.
Obviously the "draw/edit picture" should be done in another standalone app. Then it will be nice to launch that app via `intent`:

```
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

That app should edit the image and save it "in place".

As far as I know, there are many decent image drawing/editing apps, such as Skitch, SketchBook.  But unfortunately none of them accept `ACTION_EDIT`, and save the edited image "in place".
The only two apps that support `ACTION_EDIT` of "`image/*`" are [JXWhiteboard](https://github.com/OpenJunction/JXWhiteboard) and picSay. (I got the info from the comments in [this blog](http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2012/03/writing-interactive-photo-editors-for-android/))
Although picSay can edit an image, it is not for "drawing" stuff. Neither does it saves the image "in place".
JXWhiteboard do support what I want, but its editing functionality is really poor.

In a word, I spent a lot of time, but didn't find a decent image drawing/editing app that accepts ACTION_EDIT!
I don't want to build my own image drawing app, because both Skitch and sketchBook are great.

Should I build it from scratch? Or did I missed any great app that accepts `ACTION_EDIT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obviously the "draw/edit picture" should be done in another standalone app.

That is far from obvious.

> Then it will be nice to launch that app via intent:

Please use a real MIME type.

> That app should edit the image and save it "in place".

At best, that would only be possible for images that are in a mutually-writable location (e.g., external storage).

> I spent a lot of time, but didn't find a decent image drawing/editing app that accepts ACTION_EDIT!

Photoshop Express supports `ACTION_EDIT` of images.

Comment: Thank you CommonsWare! Although this question is considered off topic, you gave me useful suggestions. Photoshop Express is not suitable for my situation. Because it's not possible to draw by that app. Besides, I installed Photoshop Express from Google Play, but it didn't show up in the app selector for ACTION_EDIT and "image/*".